# Noticeable difference in RAM consumption and startup time between Qt 5.8 and Qt 5.7 QtQuick

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.7, qt5.8

Official [docs](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/23/qt-5-8-released/) say that new Qt 5.8 release:

> Quite a few things have happened in Qt QML and Qt Quick. The QML
>   engine has gained support for caching binary representations of QML
>   and JS files on disk, reducing startup time and memory consumption of
>   the engine.

But it appears that neither startup time neither memory consumption has not been improved, furthermore it has become slower and more RAM is using.

I provided some tests.
Created a new blank project,  launched `task manager` and what I saw is:

**Memory usage:**

Qt 5.8 18.8 mb

Qt 5.7 14.2 mb

**Startup time:**

Difference about a second when I pushing a new item into a `StackView` via `URL`

So what did they improve?

Comment: I doubt that this will go anywhere beyond shooting into the dark. Have you tried it with a more complex example? Maybe the engine got bigger, but the memory consumption for the QML files is smaller? For the start-up-time I don't know, but as *caching* is mentioned, it won't help at the first startup, and maybe the cachability is not given for all kinds of sources. But as I said: I just guess around.

Comment: Interesting question, though!

Comment: @derM yep I have tried. My main project wich has more than 20k lines of code  shows the difference about 30mb. `Maybe the engine got bigger, but the memory consumption for the QML files is smaller?` May be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Cashed code and data structures from .qml/.js files will be generated on the first start-up. The resulting .qmlc and .jsc cache files will be used for further start-ups, so you will not see any difference the first time your app starts.

> My main project wich has more than 20k lines of code

It also depends on how your qml code is arranged and how big your qml files is, you need to minimize creating qml objects at start-up, divide your qml files into logical units and use Loader when possible.